# fitting a model of each subject and perform a t-test over the estimated parameters

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, t-test

In my field, psychophysics/experimental psychology, sometimes a lot of measures are collected for each subject. Then, a model is fitted for each subject and with the estimated parameters sometimes a global test like a t-test or ANOVA is performed to reach conclusions. It seems that this approach sometimes produces wrong conclusions and I wanted to know references that already made this point. Below a toy example:

Let's suppose that I want to know whether the color of an object (red or green) influences its visibility. To measure visibility I presented a tiny object in a computer screen and ask the subject to report whether can or cannot see the object. After she responds, I display another tiny object and so on. I use four different sizes and two colors and presented them randomly. Each size and color is presented 50 times. This is a possible outcome of the experiment:

[image: Results toy example]

Each panel shows the data for one subject. The y-axis is the frequency of reports 'yes, I saw it'. The curves are cumulative normal distributions fitted using generalized linear models and the vertival lines are the estimated means of the underlying distributions.

The confidence intervals of the fits indicate that the color influences the visibility for each subject. For subjects 1,2 and 3 green is easier to perceive. For subjects 4,5 and 6 red is easier. Given that the color does not affect equally each subject, it is possible that if I use the mean of the fitted distributions to perform a t-test it turns out not significant.

So sometimes in my field, based on the results of the t-test, it is concluded that color does not affect visibility. The individual analysis for each subject is not performed and discussed. So I am searching for references (articles/books) that point this problem out.

Below the code of the toy example in R:

```
 library('plyr')
 library('ggplot2')

 set.seed(100)
 n<-50
 size<-1:4
 prob<-c(0.1,.3,.5,.7)

 variables1<-expand.grid(subject=1:3,color=c('red','green'))
 df1<-ddply(variables1,.(subject,color),function(d){
     if (d$color=='red') nyes<-rbinom(4,n,prob)
     if (d$color=='green') nyes<-rbinom(4,n,prob+.2)
     data.frame(size,nyes,nno=n-nyes,p=nyes/n) 
 })

 variables2<-expand.grid(subject=4:6,color=c('red','green'))
 df2<-ddply(variables2,.(subject,color),function(d){
    if (d$color=='green') nyes<-rbinom(4,n,prob)
    if (d$color=='red') nyes<-rbinom(4,n,prob+.2)
    data.frame(size,nyes,nno=n-nyes,p=nyes/n) 
 })

 dat<-rbind(df1,df2)

 curves<-ddply(dat,.(subject,color),function(d){
   model<-glm(cbind(nyes,nno)~size,binomial(probit),d)
   x<-seq(0,5,.1)
   y<-predict(model,data.frame(size=x),type='response',se.fit=T)
   data.frame(x,y=y$fit,ymin=y$fit-y$se.fit,ymax=y$fit+y$se.fit)
 })

 means<-ddply(dat,.(subject,color),function(d){
   model<-glm(cbind(nyes,nno)~size,binomial(probit),d)
   coe<-coef(model)
   m<- -coe[[1]]/coe[[2]]
  data.frame(m)
 })

 q<-ggplot()+
   facet_wrap(~subject)+
   geom_point(data=dat,aes(x=size,y=p,color=color))+
   geom_line(data=curves,aes(x=x,y=y,color=color))+
   geom_ribbon(data=curves,aes(x=x,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax,fill=color),alpha=.3)+
   geom_linerange(data=means,aes(x=m,color=color),ymin=0,ymax=.5)
 q

 t.test(m~color,data=means,paired=T)
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing a t-test here is rather naive. The data are not independent since each subject has repeated measures. This must be dealt with. One way to do so is a multilevel model (in `R` see `lme4' or 'nlme` packages).

The fact that some individuals see green more easily and others see red more easily allows two approaches: 1) Averaging over people, we see no overall effect (this is what the t-test does). 2) An alternative is to look for reasons why the people differ (using characteristics of the people as independent variables).